# Does the avenger arise from bones or ashes?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, meaning, aeneis, vergilius

A famous quote of Dido's from *Aeneid* 4.625 is

> exoriare aliquis nostris ex ossibus ultor

of which my preferred poetic translation is Fitzgerald's

> Rise up from my bones, avenging spirit

However, I've seen the translation done several ways, and some of them use 'ashes' instead of 'bones' presumably for *ossibus*. I'm under the impression from a Latin dictionary that *ossibus* refers strictly to bones. So why are there variant translations of this seemingly simple word?

I guess there are two sub-questions, any of which could answer the main question:

- Did the meaning of *ossibus* change over time? If so, what was the meaning of the word at the time of Virgil's writing.
- Is 'ashes' used only in translations where they want the two syllables for poetic meter or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perseus offers two English translations of Aeneid, including [your passage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D584).

[Theodore C. Williams, 1910](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0054%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D584), writes:

> Arise, Out of my dust, unknown Avenger, rise!

[John Dryden](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D584) writes:

> Rise some avenger of our Libyan blood

They both take poetic license in expressing the same idea.
The word [*os*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DO%3Aentry+group%3D31%3Aentry%3Dos2) indeed means only bones, not ashes.
The point is not taking it literally.
I think the Latin original and the two English translation are equivalent: here "ashes", "bones", and "blood" mean the same thing (metonymically).

Comment: Except that Dryden does not say "rise FROM our blood"; he says "rise, some avenger OF our Libyan blood". "Of" goes with "avenger".